# Insert a "Select Value" option in dropdown list from array using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I a droppdown list that gets its values from an Array. It works perfectly, the only issue I have is that I need to insert a "Select Value" option the will be the one shown when the page loads. The issue is that my dropdown list gives you the option of selecting a "Year", but by default the first option is... let's say "2009", but if I have to select that specific year, nothing will happens because the way I have it setup...

```
  $("#DropDownChoice").change(function () {
 //Code here
 });
```

...it will only runs the "code" if something "changes". I have used:

```
$("#DropDownChoice").select(function() {
//code
});
```

..and it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the JS Array and how you are binding it to the dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `prepend` to put an option at the beginning of the menu.

```
$(function() {
    $("#DropDownChoice").prepend($('<option>', { 
        value: '',
        text: 'Select Value'
    }));
});
```